# Javafx audit logging

Tags: java, logging, javafx, audit

I have an assignment in Javafx to take a basic login application and have it produce an audit log that includes the entries the user put in the text boxes and the buttons pressed along with the date and time. I have searched high and low and I cannot find an example that I can make work with my application. Can someone provide me a basic example of how to implement the audit log or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For a professional application, many people use [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html), or [Apache Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). However, since this is an assignment, I assume your instructor wishes you to keep a log using your own File I/O.

I would suggest implementing a method called `log(String message)` which opens your audit file and appends a line to the end with the current timestamp and given message. Then, everywhere in your application you need to log something, you simply call your own `log(message)` function.

For more help with File IO, try reading through [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm), or searching google for a good one.

Comment: How is this implemented? I understand using BufferedWriter but how do I get log(message) to work?